# Add method specialization for all enumeration classes in C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++17, strong-typing

I have the following methods (broadly speaking) in my bitstream class:

```
class BitStream
{
    void StoreBits( unsigned int data, unsigned int numBits );
    
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void WriteType( T value ) { StoreBits( value, sizeof(T) * 8 ) );

    template<>
    void WriteType( float value ) { StoreBits( *(unsigned int*)&value, sizeof(float) * 8 ) );
};
```

Someone has thrown a strongly type enum class at WriteType, and obviously the enum does not automatically convert to an unsigned integer.

What can I do to write a specialization that handles all enumeration cases using the same function naming?

This is a trivialization of the problem - I have enum class instances being thrown at a number of other BitStream member methods that I have to handle, such as ReadType, StreamType (read or write), SmallestRangeWrite<Min,Max>() etc.

I have C++17 support available. I know there is std::is_enum, but how can I specialize on that here, especially at compile time?

Could I somehow write:

```
template<typename T>inline void BitStream::WriteType( T value ) 
{
  if (type_is_enum())
    StoreEnum<T>(value)
  else
    StoreBits( value, sizeof(T) * 8 ) );
}
```

I need to ensure that the StoreBits method is not compiled when T is an enumeration. Simply avoiding it at runtime with a branch isn't enough.

Comment: You seem to know `is_enum`. Just do `type_is_enum()` --> `is_enum_v<T>` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PnsTEz).

Comment: Don't forget `if constexpr`

Comment: Please make a [mre] What is `u32`? Does the code compiler, or does it do the wrong thing for `enum` types?

Comment: @cigien Where is 'is_enum_v<T>' - I see is_enum<T>::value; even so how can I ensure the two distinct code paths are compiled, or does that just work?

Comment: In C++17, `is_enum_v<T>` is an alias for `is_enum<T>::value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test to see if the type is an enum *and* if it's not convertible to `u32`. This allows you to distinguish between normal `enum` and `enum class`. If it's an enum but is not convertible to `u32`, then it's an `enum class`:

```
template<typename T>
inline void BitStream::WriteType(T value) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T> && !std::is_convertible_v<T, u32>)
        // enum class
        StoreEnum<T>(value)
    else
       // normal enum or other type that is convertible to u32
        StoreBits(value, sizeof(T) * 8 ));
}
```

Since your `StoreEnum` and `StoreBits` function templates can't take both, you need to use `if constexpr` here to avoid the type check when compiling.

Comment: This seems resonable, but maybe my compiler is not actually C++17 because I have is_enum, but not is_enum_v, nor is_convertible_v. Is that shorthand for is_enum<T>::value ?

Comment: @Steven Yes, it's just a shorthand. Which compiler are you using? With GCC and Clang, you need to use the `-std=c++17` (or `-std=gnu++17` to also get GCC extensions) when compiling.

Comment: So I am having an issue where 'StoreBits' is still trying to be compiled even though the type is an enum; I know that at runtime the correct branch will be taken, but is there a way to have this done at compile to so that the StoreBits method is not even *considered* for compilation if T is an enum? I suppose it can just be used as a condition on a template argument?

Comment: @Steven Then you need `if constexpr`. All this information should be in the question itself.

Comment: @Steven Yep. Updated the answer.

Comment: @cigien I have updated the question, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3):

The best feature of C++17 (that is my personal opinion) is *constexpr if*. That means that you don't need to define explicit specializations. That would work:

```cpp
template<typename T>inline void BitStream::WriteType(T value) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>)
        StoreEnum<T>(value);
    else
        StoreBits(value, sizeof(T) * 8);
}
```

Using constexpr if is important as you run into the risk of the compilation failure if either `StoreEnum` or `StoreBits` are undefined for the type `T`.

Comment: @NikosC. What happens if `T` is of type `double`? Would the `StoreEnum<T>(T)` be defined?

Comment: Right so this replaces me having to punt it into a StoreHelper<std::is_enum<T>::value>::Store(T) where I specialize StoreHelper for true and false just so I can ensure only the right code is compiled for type T, right?

Comment: @Steven, if I understood you correctly, the answer is yes.